# static linking results in cant open source file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, static-libraries

Okay so i pretty much want to use this library
https://github.com/stevemk14ebr/PolyHook_2_0

I cloned the Github and as stated changed the CMAKE to STATIC_LINKING so my .lib file gets created instead of the unit test after that.

What I did so far: IMAGES

1. [Added Include Directorys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NfoT.jpg)
2. [Directory of header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZirHQ.jpg)
3. [Added library Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQwxl.jpg)
4. [Added the lib to Additional Dependencies + Directory of lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2moQ.jpg)
5. [Inside look of Visual Studio with all the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gx2C.jpg)
6. [Solution Directory for completness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HAFm.jpg)
7. [Output because ppl asked for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7HZX.jpg)

I have googled a bit and thats how Static linking is supposed to be working so im confused at what I did wrong? Can someone enlight me.

Comment: Add the proper include path to your project properties.

Comment: Rather than the showing a picture of the Error List tab, switch over to the Output tab, copy the plain text in the Output tab, and paste it into the question. The contents of the Output tab are often much better than the abbreviated messages in the Error List. If you're really lucky the extra information in the Output tab may solve the problem for you.

Comment: 1>c:\users\vaio\source\repos\dll1\dependencies\polyhook\headers\exceptions\breakpointhook.hpp(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'headers/Exceptions/AVehHook.hpp': No such file or directory Is the only thing that comes at the output window which is the same as the errors are giving

Comment: What you've run up against has nothing to do with the fact you're linking statically. The build process doesn't get to the linking, it fails to compile. John's answer probably has the right of it. I can't tell because at the moment I can't look at your images, [one of many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4581301) why questions should not present significant information in images. Use text.

Comment: The images are not code and do even described what I did without clicking it.

Comment: Code is important, but it's not the only thing. *Everything* needed to understand and answer the question should be in the question, not linked from the question. Images have their uses, but should be supplementary information unless the question is about the image (ie. Why is this pixel the wrong colour?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two errors.

```
#include ""
```

is the cause of the error that says `expected a file name`.

Your include directory setting is `$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\Polyhook\headers` but the error message states

```
cannot open source file "headers/Misc.hpp"
```

This clearly indicates that 'headers' is in the source code and therefore should not be in the include directory settings. In effect you're telling the compiler to look for '$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\Polyhook\headers\headers\Misc.hpp' which obviously it doesn't find. Change your include directory setting to `$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\Polyhook`

And user4581301 is right, the error list tab is worse than useless, apart from anything else it mixes up the order of error messages. Look at the output tab instead.

Comment: The Misc.hpp is literally inside this Folder $(SolutionDir)Dependencies\Polyhook\headers\headers\ so the path has to be correct, I changed it to your suggestion but as expected this isnt an answer to my question and the cause is something else. I also added the Output tab and even copy pasted the whole path that it gave as an error and it finds it at the explorer

Comment: @Ojav According to your image 2 above Misc.hpp is in $(SolutionDir)Dependencies\Polyhook\headers not $(SolutionDir)Dependencies\Polyhook\headers\headers

Comment: @Ojav Your picture of the "headers" folder doesn't show another "headers" subdir.

Comment: Okay so i pretty much created a new Project and it seems to be correct and understandable doesnt work on my main project but thats fine

Comment: Thanks for helping me appreciate it even if most guys at stackoverflow downvote !

Comment: @Ojav, no problem. I've just remembered the other reason to avoid the error list tab. As well as compiler errors it also shows 'intellisense' errors. which can be misieading.Only compiler errors really count.

Comment: @john will do! Can only learn by doing it wrong! Thanks so much again <3

Comment: @Ojav also keep an eye on compiler warnings. They tell you that even though something compiled you should take a second look because it probably doesn't do what you're expecting.